# Multi Subquery count function unable to take the stress of multiple selects

Tags: mysql, sql, count

This has me stumped.

**MySQL**

```
UPDATE sets SET sets.current_count = (SELECT COUNT(leads_auto.set_id) AS current_count FROM leads_auto WHERE leads_auto.set_id =  (SELECT sets.set_id AS setID FROM sets WHERE sets.on_off = 0)) WHERE sets.on_off = 0
```

Seems right doesn't it? Update the record `current_count` with the total number of rows in `leads_auto` which have the `set_id` value of the `set_id` of the `sets` table where the value of its `on_off` column is 0.

**yet I get this error**

```
#1093 - You can't specify target table 'sets' for update in FROM clause
```

I looked around and someone mentioned that it has to do with the operation being cyclic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a temporary table for the result of `SET`

```
UPDATE sets
SET sets.current_count = 
                (
                SELECT COUNT(leads_auto.set_id) AS current_count
                FROM leads_auto
                WHERE leads_auto.set_id = 
                                (
                                    SELECT set_id
                                    FROM
                                    (
                                        SELECT sets.set_id AS setID
                                        FROM sets
                                        WHERE sets.on_off = 0
                                    ) c
                                )
                )
WHERE sets.on_off = 0
```

Comment: Worked Flawlessly, and taught me something.